# no loading sign while navigating through AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a music player in my website that keeps playing even while navigating.THe problem is that on the tab there shows no loading sign, just the website favicon. Right now the screen just freezes for a few seconds and then the next page shows.I also want there to be a loading sign, it looks official that way. How can i do this?

Comment: What do you mean by loading sign ? -.-

Comment: That's because it's using using ajax and not reloading the page so the browser doesn't recognise it?

Comment: Do you mean the browser's built-in loading indicator? That only shows when the browser is loading a page, not when AJAX is operating behind the scenes. That's why everyone displays a GIF indicator.

Comment: The most you can do is change the title to "Loading..." then change it back when it's done.

Comment: u mean on click on a link run a function to change the title and then a callback after the load() function to change the title again?

Comment: how can I? I'm a bit new to the jquery load() function and the ajax navigation system pls. tell me how.

Comment: also how is it different from whay myspace or facebook does for its chatbox? In those sites the loading indicator works.

Comment: I don't use either of those sites in my web browser, so i can't answer that. Changing the title is as easy as `document.title = "Loading..."; `and then changing it back in the success of the ajax request.

Comment: in the succes of ajax request meaning just a simple comma and a callback function right?

Comment: if that's how the ajax method you are using works, then yes.

Comment: for some reason the gif freezes and also does the screen. it's like i click on a link, Freeze for 1 min, and then the new screen. why?